# How to add number of days in a text box with MaskedEditExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to add number of days in a date which shows in textbox using javascript on text change event. Please help me out...

```
<tr id="AbsentDays" runat="server">
    <td align="right" style="width: 33%">
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="No of days"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td id="Td5" runat="server">&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td id="Td6" align="left" colspan="3" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDayAbsent" Width="80px"
            onchange="javascript: ontextchanged();"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>

    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDurationFrom" runat="server" Text="Duration From"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 36%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDurationFrom" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:maskededitextender id="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDurationFrom"
            mask="99/99/9999" masktype="Date" errortooltipenabled="True" culturename="en-GB"
            cultureampmplaceholder="AM;PM" culturecurrencysymbolplaceholder="£" culturedateformat="DMY"
            culturedateplaceholder="/" culturedecimalplaceholder="." culturethousandsplaceholder=","
            culturetimeplaceholder=":" enabled="True" />
        <cc1:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDurationFrom"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy" enabled="True" />
    </td>

    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDurationTo" runat="server" Text="Duration To"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDurationTo" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:maskededitextender id="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDurationTo"
            mask="99/99/9999" masktype="Date" errortooltipenabled="True" culturename="en-GB"
            cultureampmplaceholder="AM;PM" culturecurrencysymbolplaceholder="£" culturedateformat="DMY"
            culturedateplaceholder="/" culturedecimalplaceholder="." culturethousandsplaceholder=","
            culturetimeplaceholder=":" enabled="True" />
        <cc1:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDurationTo"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy" enabled="True" />
    </td>

</tr>
```

Javascript

```
function ontextchanged()
{
    var dayAbsent = document.getElementById('<%=txtDayAbsent.ClientID%>').value;
    var myDate = new Date((document.getElementById('<%=txtDurationTo.ClientID%>')).value);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(dayAbsent));
}
```

on change event of **txtDayAbsent** i want to add no of days in txtDurationTo 
nowhow to set this date to txtDurationTo text box with dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extrat the day,month and year part of the date and then make a date with require formate. like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function ontextchanged() {
            var dayAbsent = document.getElementById('<%=txtDayAbsent.ClientID%>').value;
            var myDate = new Date((document.getElementById('<%=txtDurationTo.ClientID%>')).value);
            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(dayAbsent));

            var dd = myDate.getDate();
             var mm = myDate.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = myDate.getFullYear();
            if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
            var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;              

             document.getElementById('<%=txtDurationTo.ClientID%>').value = today;
             alert(today);
        }    </script>
```

Comment: This is exactly working fine ..!!! thank you..But the problem is , when i try to get value after setting in txtDurationTo.Text than its giving me mm/dd/yyyy format.